# At what height should I install my (coat) rack?

Tags: bedroom, closet, measurement, hanger, fixtures

I'm planning to install a coat rack on the right side of my bedroom closet, at the place marked with `*`:

```
+----------------+
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
| +--------+     |
| | Closet |*    |
+-+--------+-    |
             Door
```

(drawing not to scale; projection from top)

My question: How do I decide at which height to install the rack? I'd like to do something better than just eyeball what seems reasonable.

Should it depend on:

- Ceiling height?
- Closet height?
- Closet handle height?
- Door handle height?
- Door height?
- other things?

... and what kind of dependence?

Additional info:

- I don't have coats which go down to knee or foot level - only waist-high coats. On the other hand, this rack isn't really for coats - those go on a coat rack at the entrance to my apartment.
- There are other coat racks in the apartment, but they're all hanging off of door tops, like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4C2O.jpg).

Comment: I would recommend between high enough to keep coats off the floor and low enough to reach without jumping.  You are using it, make it easy for you.  It is not rocket science and the only thing you need is for it not to fall down.

Comment: Take your largest, tallest coat, put it on a hanger and experiment what height is the most comfortable for you to hang and unhang

Comment: Is it going to be the only coat rack in the house? If not then you may want to make them all the same height for consistency. If it is the only one however, then it seems reasonable to me to just eyeball what seems reasonable.

Comment: @crip659: Those are obvious constraints, but what about the exact value? It's not rocket science, it's design science :-)

Comment: @JACK: That results in a range, not a point...

Comment: To turn @JACK's statement from a range into a point: take your largest, tallest coat, put it on a hanger and make sure there is 5cm of clearance at the floor level (so you can vacuum there).

Comment: @GlenYates: No, it is one of several racks - but the others are hanging off of door tops, like [this one](https://i.imgur.com/D8MhUl3.jpg)

Comment: @MiG: If my coats are all waist-high, that will mean I put the coat hanger up at about chest-level...

Comment: You're adding a lot of extra conditions in these comments. It would help if you could sum these up in your original post, rather than us discovering new constraints at every turn.

Comment: @MiG: Added as much as I could to the original post, but I'm not sure what you guys will ask about...

Comment: Voted to close because this is opinion based, where to hang is opinion based, how to best hang is not.  What surprises me is with her background (click on her image), she doesn't know where to hang a coat rack.   I'll probably get snipped for this, but really, I mean really, she should be able to figure this out on her own. .

Comment: It is not even design science.  The height depends on the person and length of the coats.  A 4foot 11 inch person needs a different height that a 6.5 foot person, unless the short person wants to use a step ladder every time.  Put a long coat on a hanger, lift the hanger and coat as high as you can.  Place the coat rack 3 or 4 inches below that height.

Comment: the main thing is to decide if you want 2 rows or just 1. if just one, put it shoulder height.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  I was thinking the same thing. With her precise criticism of all the comments, you'd think she could install a rack in a closet. We'll go down together... lol

Comment: @crip659: So there is no rule, no standard, no custom, to this?

Comment: If stuff does not matter for safety, then most of it is what looks good(eye balling) to you.  You don't even need a rack/rod for hangers, you can use shelves and fold up your coats, if you want.

Comment: @crip659: That's an answer, I suppose. It's not for coats, it's for having a place to throw clothes on without folding them up or leaving them on the bed etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to want an exact answer where none really exist then here:

According to the experts at [Home Décor Bliss](https://homedecorbliss.com/how-high-should-a-coat-rack-be/), the average height of a coat rack is about 5 feet; this height keeps even long coats from hanging on the ground, but is reachable to most individuals.

So, 60 inches it is.

Comment: Would probably be better state this in standard units: 154.4 cm.

Comment: Whose standard, @einpoklum? ;)

Comment: @FreeMan: [Everybody's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units).